# nfcpy - Read RC-S380 Serial Number

Tags: python-3.x, nfc, smartcard

I'm using python 3 and nfcpy 1.0.3 and trying to read the serial number of RC-S380 reader. We're using multiple readers and  need this to differentiate them.

I can read the S/N using Sony Felica Driver (and by calling WinSCard). However, with different driver (using libusb via Zadig), I don't know the method/function to read it.

Thanks,

Irfan

Comment: Which manufacturer is your reader from and what is given in the according documentation?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it's Sony. And, as mentioned as well, I can read S/N using Sony driver and WinSCard.